# Convert variable to Enum type C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Suppose I have these Enums:

```
public enum A{}
public enum B{}
public enum C{}
```

The Enums define a set of columns needed for mapping a `SqlBulkCopy` in the following method:

```
public void CommandBulkInsertBuilder<Tp, TEnum>(Tp dataTable, TEnum e)
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible {
    //Initialize
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_conString);
    DataTable dt = dataTable as DataTable;

    //Map columns based on Enum type
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        List<string> database = new List<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(e)));


        if (database.Contains(column.ColumnName))
        {
            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
        }
    }

    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = $"dbo.Temp" + typeof(e).Name;
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt); }
```

I am getting thrown an exception when trying to use the argument `e` as a type when it's currently a variable. How do I convert into a specific Enum type? I have tried switching and casting around, but I can't seem to get it working.
[image]

EDIT: The method is called by the following code throwing `System.ArgumentException: 'Type provided must be an Enum. (Parameter 'enumType')`:

```
List<Enum> enums = new List<Enum>() { new TblDogs(), new TblDogHealth(), new TblDogPedigree()};

foreach (Enum ee in enums)
{
    bool a = da.BulkInsert(dt, ee, da.CommandBulkInsertBuilder);
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to use `e` at all, other than trying to get its type. How about remove `e`, and use `typeof(TEnum)` instead?

Comment: @Sweeper It casts the following exception when doing so:
System.ArgumentException: 'Type provided must be an Enum. (Parameter 'enumType')'

I don't think it can be done like that since the type is currently generic. I think casting e as our desired Enum type would solve the problem, but I am clueless of how to do so.

Comment: No, it can certainly be done like that. You can also do `Enum.GetNames<TEnum>()` What type actually is `TEnum`? Can you show how you call `CommandBulkInsertBuilder`?

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry about pointing something out - I am still learning. The method is looped through a list of Enums. I will just now include it in the post

Comment: I see, so you don't need the `TEnum` type parameter. Just take an `Enum` parameter. Then use `e.GetType()`.

Comment: Or, just take a `Type` instead. The `enums` list can be a `List<Type>`.

Comment: @Sweeper I solved it - thanks for the help!