# Type conversion from a collection of generics to a collection of a specific type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

Suppose the following code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Dog> TblDogs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();
public ObservableCollection<Health> TblDogHealth { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Health>();
public ObservableCollection<Pedigree> TblDogPedigree { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Pedigree>();

private ObservableCollection<T>? GetList<T>(Enum e)
{
    switch (e.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "TblDogs": return TblDogs;
        case "TblDogHealth": return TblDogHealth;
        case "TblDogPedigree": return TblDogPedigree;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The method is supposed to return an existing collections as properties from a class within the class itself based on the `Enum` type supplied as argument (thereby making a value type point to a reference type making `IEnumerable` methods available).

The code provides a type conversion failure though as the following:
[image]

I tried making the custom data type inherit from an empty class and making the return type of the method to fit the inherited class, which didn't work. Is there a workaround for a problem like this?

Comment: Is this like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77463642/5133585), where at the callsite of `GetList`, you don't actually know the type of the enum? If so, this is kind of impossible.

Comment: @Sweeper Hi again and thanks for the help yesterday! The thing is, I am looping based on a set of enums I have matching the columns in a database and trying to make reuseable functions to populate a set of collections from a set of distinct tables. Yesterday I simply needed the name of the columns, which we fixed, but now I am trying to infer aa already existing collection from a supplied enum. I added some lines to clarify the properties already exist with custom data types, but I have no clue how to make them fit the generic function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not guarantee that the return type matches the enum type. It would be perfectly legal to call:

```
var dogList = GetList<Health>(TypeEnum.Pedigree);
```

You can either *explicitly* cast:

```
private ObservableCollection<T>? GetList<T>(Enum e)
{
    switch (e.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "TblDogs": return TblDogs as ObservableCollection<T>;
        case "TblDogHealth": return TblDogHealth as ObservableCollection<T>;
        case "TblDogPedigree": return TblDogPedigree as ObservableCollection<T>;
    }
    return null;
}
```

which would return `null` if the requested output type does not match the enum value.

Or just not use a generic method (since your method isn't really generic) and use real type safety:

```
private ObservableCollection<Dog> GetDogList()
{
    return TblDogs;
}
private ObservableCollection<Health> GetHealthList()
{
    return TblDogHealth;
}
private ObservableCollection<Pedigree> GetPedigreeList()
{
    return TblDogPedigree;
}
```

Comment: Casting explicitly worked. Thing is, I know for sure the method will never be called with another enum type other than the ones I defined so like you say it really isn't generic per se, but made to fit an already existing method to loop based on the provided enums.

Thanks for the help!